# AHK: am I correct in my understanding of the GUI client area width?

Tags: windows, user-interface, client, textarea, autohotkey

On AHK forum, in **[this thread](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=69581)**, I received this answer:

> the control is bigger than the client area but it will always be "underneath", or limited to, the client window

Having read this, I became quite confused about the width of client area. I've always thought that the width of the client area was equal to the sum of widths of all controls (given that they are all located in one horizontal line and there is only that one line in the window), plus the distances between them, and plus the margins (the distance between the border of the window and the first control and the distance between the last control and the border), but it seems that I was wrong assuming that.

So, can anyone here, please, explain to me the relationship between GUI controls' widths and the client area width. I asked this question there, but it seems that the answer there is not coming soon.

Answer (score 1):

The non-client area of a control is the border/titlebar and so on - typically drawn by windows in a consistent style for your theme.

The client area is everything *inside* the borders - the part that makes the control unique, and which you normally access when painting.

Windows tells a window to paint itself with two messages: `WM_NCPAINT` and `WM_PAINT` - the default handling of `WM_NCPAINT` for e.g. a top-level window will draw a border/title-bar according to style flags set on the window, and your current theme. The default handling of `WM_PAINT` will do nothing (background color is handled by WM_ERASEBKGND)

Comment: Hello Eric, thank you for your answer. So, if I increase the width of text control by means of `GuiControl, Move` command, will the client area width increase too?

Comment: @Benny-D: Yes. The relation in between client and full size is normally fixed.